# Oracle SQL: Find {tags} in a sql string

Tags: sql, string, oracle, replace, tags

I have SQL strings that my users write. They look like:

```
SELECT Name, Age from Users WHERE Name LIKE '%a%' AND {UsersWhere}
```

On the oracle server side when such an SQL is to be executed I want to replace the {tags} first. The replacements for the {tags} will be valid SQL sub strings I am holding in a table. Pre-manufactered sub sqls. So the treated string will be valid SQL.

Is there some fancy build-in Oracle function to make this happen?

Thanks for a hint!

Comment: How are you running the user-supplied SQL - as dynamic SQL through PL/SQL? And by 'fancy', do you mean something like [`replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions153.htm)?

Comment: I want to run the SQL ina function - so that would be PL/SQL.

Comment: Yes, by fancy I mean for example a oracle helper function that would return all found {tags} or something. I could then loop through them to get the substitutes and make a replace on the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written a small function for anyone interested:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SA.REPLACE_VARIABLES (p_sql             IN VARCHAR2)
   RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
   vs_return           VARCHAR2 (4000);


   -- Deklarationen  
   vs_sql              VARCHAR2(4000);

   vs_substring        VARCHAR2(4000);
   vs_variable         VARCHAR2(200);

   vs_variable_content VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
   vs_sql := p_sql;

   IF INSTR(p_sql, '{') > 0 THEN

    vs_substring := vs_sql;

    WHILE LENGTH(vs_substring) > 0 LOOP

        IF INSTR(vs_substring, '{') <> 0 
        THEN

            vs_variable := SUBSTR(vs_substring, INSTR(vs_substring, '{'), INSTR(vs_substring, '}') - INSTR(vs_substring, '{') + 1);

            -- Do whatever you want with the variable
            --vs_sql := REPLACE(vs_sql, vs_variable, vs_variable_content); 

            -- Substring verkürzen
            vs_substring := SUBSTR(vs_substring, INSTR(vs_substring, vs_variable) + LENGTH(vs_variable) + 1);

        ELSE

            vs_substring := '';

        END IF;

    END LOOP;

   END IF;

   RETURN vs_sql;

EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      -- Err -handle

END REPLACE_VARIABLES;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd just keep it simple:

```
v_sql := REPLACE(v_sql, '{UsersWhere}', '...whatever you need...');
```